# PHP-MySQL- I want to compare any values from an array with the _POST values i am receiving from form

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am storing list of property types like Apartment, Penthouse etc for a given property in an array in a table. Now I want to display all the fields from that table whenever someone searches for Apartment or Penthouse.

Till now i have inserted the list of values using serialize into the table. An also able to fetch values using deserialize. Now i want search for particular value from that array. If value found, i need to display all details from that row.

```
if($_POST['action'] == "add_property"){
  $ptype     = serialize($_POST['ptype']);
  $proomtype = serialize($_POST['proomtype']);

  $query2 = query("SELECT * FROM properties");
  confirm($query2);
  while($row = fetch_array($query2)) {
     $ptype     = unserialize($row['ptype']);
     $proomtype = unserialize($row['proomtype']);

     echo "ptype: $ptype  proomtype: $proomtype";
  }
```

}

I'm a beginner to MySQl. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance. Also if there is any other simplest way where i can store a list of values in a table, fetch them, compare them and delete them. Would be much appreciated.

Comment: Pls show sample records from your table, so we know how your data looks like. Most likely, you have a table design problem.

Comment: dummy                                       ||  dummy2                 =======================================================
s:21:"Residential,Penthouse";   ||  s:4:"4BHK"; 
 ===============================
s:21:"Residential,Penthouse";   || s:4:"2BHK";

Comment: @Shadow Also if there is any other simplest way where i can store a list of values in a table, fetch them, compare them and delete them. Would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return if all values match.

```
SELECT * FROM properties 
WHERE column1 LIKE 
'%serialsize($ptype)%' 
OR column2 LIKE 
'%serialsize($proomtype)%'
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I want to compare values from an unserialized array like "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE my_array = ($comparing_value1, $comparing_value2)"

Comment: I made changes in my answer

Comment: Thanks. It works great. But just wondering if there's any other simplest way, where i can store, compare & delete any such values easily?

Comment: This is one of the easiest if the user change or delete something just update your column.                 Ps. If my answer works pleace accept the answer.

Comment: Hey @stefo91  . My query is not woking with 2 conditions. 
`$query = ("SELECT * FROM properties WHERE ptype LIKE '%{$ptype}%' OR proomtype LIKE '%{$proomtype}%'");`

It works with single LIKE condition. But not working for 2 conditions.